# How to limit user for access only the information of his own

Tags: cakephp, acl

I follow Acl example in manual of cake .
 When success I have more question for apply 
Acl to My project

```
 function initDB() {
    $group = & $this->User->Group;
    //Allow admins to everything
    $group->id = 1;
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers');

    //allow managers to posts and widgets
    $group->id = 2;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets');

    //allow users to only add and edit on posts and widgets
    $group->id = 3;
    $this->Acl->deny($group, 'controllers');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Posts/edit');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets/add');
    $this->Acl->allow($group, 'controllers/Widgets/edit');
    //we add an exit to avoid an ugly "missing views" error message
    echo "all done";
    exit;
}
```

In code 
1.How to limit user to access only the information of his own  
2.I need to alert when deny user access to action
3.when login as any role I can't acess to logout action

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need row based acl, not the action based one you have shown http://jmcneese.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/update-row-level-model-access-control-for-cakephp/

Comment: OMG it looks like it will be harder the next step
I also understand the ACL is not much 
can you explain me for different between ACL and Permissionable

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP's ACL component can be a little disappointing.  Compared to the ACL component in the Zend framework it seems quite lacking.

I've never tried the plugin that dogmatic69 refers to.  In my application I have decided to use ACL for what ACL is good at and find other ways of permission checking in situations where I need to restrict access to rows and other things, instead of using a plugin.

My only concern about using a plugin at this point is that CakePHP 2.0 is now released as Alpha and using this plugin could delay / hinder you in upgrading if you choose to.  Development on this plugin does seem to be fairly active however, so there is a good chance it will be updated to work with 2.0 (if there are problems to begin with).

Comment: this is my first cake project .You can guide me to use Acl or not